# Mobile hotspot of my android device not showing in xubuntu

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, additional-drivers

I recently installed Xubuntu on my system (dual boot with windows 10), but the hotspot of my mobile is not showing in the available networks list, while there is no such problem in windows. Also I have another machine with lubuntu on it and it isn't able to detect the hotspot either. I use the hotspot to connect to internet so it is really uncomfortable to connect the usb cable for tethring everytime I have to connect to the internet. The output of `sudo lshw -C` network command is as follows

```
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
       logical name: enp2s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: 98:29:a6:45:1a:7b
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b4204000-b4204fff memory:b4200000-b4203fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlp3s0
       version: 31
       serial: e8:2a:44:d2:72:89
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.4.0-42-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:134 memory:b4000000-b41fffff
```

Edit - I tried changing my hotspot's frequency from 2.4 Ghz to 5 Ghz and it worked, but I still don't understand why it would not detect it at 2.4 Ghz frequency. To me it seems that there is a problem with the drivers.

Comment: Is the correct country code set?  In terminal check `iw reg get`

Answer (score 1):

Check the band, does your 2.4 GHz or 5
if your laptop supports 5 GHZ?
Most new mobiles have both bands but old laptops might just have 2.4
In this case change band from your mobile

Comment: Well I don't think it's a hardware issue as I mentioned there are no hiccups with windows, so it seems to be a problem with the drivers.
Although I did changing the frequency of my mobile's hotspot to 5Ghz from 2.4 Ghz and to my surprise it worked with 5Ghz but could not detect it at 2.4 Ghz.

Comment: In this case your driver might just be supporting just one band of frequency

Comment: The ath10k module supports dual band

Answer (score 0):

have you selected third-party software while installing Xubuntu
if yes check additional drivers in menu, you will find your propitiatory drivers there

Comment: Yes I had selected that option, in the additional drivers menu, only drivers for my graphic card are there.

Comment: this is for your specific wi-fi card, go to the `https://github.com/ajaybhatia/Qualcomm-Atheros-QCA9377-Wifi-Linux` and download zip file by clicking on `code=>download zip` then extract it and run install.sh, reboot and it should work.

Comment: Did you read the notice on the github page "This repo is depreciated and not under maintenance".  It hasn't been updated in 2 years

Comment: try `sudo nano /etc/default/crda` set REGDOMAIN=country code, for example IN for India, then reboot